# Why did Nicky do what he did to Jess in New Orleans?

Tags: plot-explanation, focus

So in *Focus*, Nicky leaves Jess in the car right after the big betting scene in New Orleans. 
I don't see why he did that. He wasn't being chased by cops or anyone. He wasn't in danger that he did it to save her life. Everything was going fine and he just left her, saying "You did great". 

**Why did Nicky leave Jess in the car right after the betting in New Orleans?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because his father taught him not to involve in any (true loving) relationship in their line of work.
Nicky knew they both fell truly for each other, so he decide to leave her for the sake of both of them.

At the end scene, his father can be seen saying these things, and because of that mistake (losing focus) he took all his earned/stolen money.